# Как сделать пустую кнопку невидимой (скрыть)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть тест, вопрос и выбор ответов .Количество ответов всегда разные . Как скрыть пустые кнопки-ответы.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam);
    back_pressed = false;
    position = 0;
    true_a = 0;

    checked = -1;

    intent = getIntent();
    questions = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_QUESTIONS);
    answers = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_ANSWERS);
    true_answers = intent.getIntArrayExtra(EXTRA_TRUE_ANSWERS);
    num_questions = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER_QUESTIONS, 10);

    answers_checked = new int[num_questions];

    tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    tvAnswerOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerOne);
    tvAnswerTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerTwo);
    tvAnswerThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerThree);
    tvAnswerFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerFour);
    tvAnswerFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerFive);
    tvAnswerSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswerSix);



    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    tvQuestion.setText(questions[position]);
    tvAnswerOne.setText(answers[position*6]);
    tvAnswerTwo.setText(answers[position*6+1]);
    tvAnswerThree.setText(answers[position*6+2]);
    tvAnswerFour.setText(answers[position*6+3]);
    tvAnswerFive.setText(answers[position*6+4]);
    tvAnswerSix.setText(answers[position*6+5]);
    setupButtonSixe(tvAnswerSix);





    tvAnswerOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAnswerTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAnswerThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAnswerFour.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAnswerFive.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAnswerSix.setOnClickListener(this);


    pbCounter = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbCounter);
    tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
    pbCounter.setMax(num_questions);
    tvCounter.setText("1 / " + num_questions);
```

private void setupButtonSixe (Button tvAnswerSix){
        String currentText = tvAnswerSix.getText().toString();
        if (currentText.isEmpty()){
            tvAnswerSix.setVisibility(GONE);
        }else {
            tvAnswerSix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    }

Не получается скрыть пятую кнопку, что не так?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Вам нужен метод setVisibility() с передаваемой константой `View.GONE` или надо прочитать ваш код и переписать его?

Comment: не чего переписывать не надо, просто подскажите как реализовать в этом примере

Comment: Тут слищком много кода, всё прочитать времени нема. Вам надо найти место, где у вас собственно назначается текст для кнопки и, если его нет - применить метод из коммента выше. Иначе тот же метод но с `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: Вот код с присвоением кнопки текста. Что то не могу сообразить дальше как? я новичок в этом деле.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте этот метод

```
private void setupButton(Button b) {
    String currentText = b.getText().toString();
    if(currentString.isEmpty()){
        b.setVisibility(GONE);
    } else {
        b.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

после того, как заполните кнопки текстом используйте этот метод для каждой кнопки(передайте кнопку в параметрах а метод проверит есть ли там текст)

Comment: @АндрейТовтин то есть вы все же хотите чтоб я переписал за вас код и заставил его работать?)

Answer (score 0):

Все работает, спасибо
Вот строка, которая присваивает текст

```
 tvAnswerFour.setText(answers[position*6+3]);
 setupButtonFour (tvAnswerFour);
```

Сам метод

```
private void setupButtonFour(Button tvAnswerFour) {
    String currentText =  tvAnswerFour.getText().toString();
    if(currentText.isEmpty()){
        tvAnswerFour.setVisibility(GONE);
    }else {
        tvAnswerFour.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}
```